# jquery 1.4 , synchronous request

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var path_data = path+"?q=map/get_data/"+param1+'/' +param2+'/'+param3+'/' +param4+'/' +param5;
var path_map_center = path+"?q=map/get_center/"+param1;

$.getJSON(path_map_center, function(data) {
   center_lati = data.lati;
   center_longi = data.longi;
});
```

// How to ensure ,`center_lati` `center_longi` are assigned before I move to next line of code. Basically how to wait till above execute.

Comment: You can't. Just put the code that requires the asynchronous operation to complete **inside** that callback function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 2):

In ajax based system it is advicable to follow async developement meaning all code which need to work with data returned by the ajax call must added to the respective callback method

```
var path_data = path + "?q=map/get_data/" + param1 + '/' + param2 + '/' + param3 + '/' + param4 +'/' + param5;
var path_map_center = path + "?q=map/get_center/" + param1;

$.getJSON(path_map_center, function(data) {
    var center_lati = data.lati;
    var center_longi = data.longi;
    //all code that need to work with center_lati and center_longi should be added here 
});
// do no put any ode that need to work with center_lati and center_longi should be added here
```

Still if you are not planning to use the async mode then use the `async` option

```
var path_data = path + "?q=map/get_data/" + param1 + '/' + param2 + '/' + param3 + '/' + param4 + '/' + param5;
var path_map_center = path + "?q=map/get_center/" + param1;

$.ajax({
    url: path_map_center,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        center_lati = data.lati;
        center_longi = data.longi;
    }
})
```

Comment: Better don't even present the `async: false` option…